# Can reanimated Chiyo use One's Own Life Reincarnation technique?

Tags: naruto

Edo Tensei render a Shinobi immortal with *endless* supply of chakra, but can Edo Tensei Chiyo use her Reincarnation Technique to someone and do it many times (since she is immortal)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your title question is yes, Chiyo can use her reincarnation technique.

I am not sure if she can do it infinitely, because she is supposed to give up all her life and energy for it. However, you can find an alternate way to infinitely revive people: she resurrects one person, and then repeatedly Edo Tensei Chiyo again.

In regards to your comment on the other post, we can compare Chiyo's technique with Pain's. Pain has never actually mastered the outerpath, which is why he has to give up his life to use it and revive people. In this case, Chiyo is the same; she has give up her life to revive one person. Since Edo Tensei Pain was expected to use his outerpath to revive people, we can also expect Chiyo to be able to do the same with her technique.

From Kishimoto's perspective, this is a really inefficient way to bring back people. That is why there are two other methods, Edo Tensei and the Rinnegan's outerpath. In case masses of people die, he can bring them back in masses. Or in other words, in case Kishimoto kills off too many Shinobi, then realizes he made a mistake by killing them, he can easily undo his error with one skill.

Comment: The last paragraph is my view/opinion on how Kishimoto operates. It seems like sometimes, he kills off too many people, like when Pain attacked Konoha. Then he decides `Wait, actually I need them to be alive` so he resurrects them all.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. she can't do it infinitely due to chakra it takes some time to recover chakra and reanimated.. i believe her body is still in Hidden Sand Graveyard

Comment: She was shown fighting Sakura in the anime, which differs from the manga.