# Can a reanimated person, be revived?

Tags: naruto

If someone is brought back to life with the endo tensi, could they also be brought back with justu's like Outer Path: Samsara of Heavenly Life Technique or what Chiyo used or again with the endo tensi?
I would like to point out the diffrence between my question and [Can reanimated Chiyo use One's Own Life Reincarnation technique?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5655/can-reanimated-chiyo-use-ones-own-life-reincarnation-technique). The latter focuses on the paradox of using a life taking justu on an immortal person, while my asks about bring back someone twice, so that there are two of them at the same time.

Also, can you use an endo tensi as a sacrifice for an endo tensi? This way you could have an army with only one sacrifice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as it is possible, as Madara has attempted to take control on Obito to use the Rinne Tensei on him. Madara usually knows what he's doing, so we can assume that reviving a reanimated person is possible in that matter.

I don't know about other techniques though.

Comment: But Obito was still alive

Comment: @TAAPSogeking: Madara however, was not. And the point was that Obito would revive Madara. You asked whether a reanimated person *be* revived, not *use* a revive technique.

Comment: I see you logic, but this is is not a answer to my question. I am trying to ask if a reanimated person can be revived twice or be used as a sacrifice.

Comment: @TAAPSogeking: Madara was reanimated, and he then *attempted* to revive himself the second time using Obito (so that his body can take on the Juubi). So yes, a reanimated person can (probably) be revived with Rinne Tensei.

Comment: Oh. Well, thanks for clearing that chapter up for me. That is what I am looking for.